# What do the subscribers/m and views/m mean?

Tags: pewdiepie-tuber-simulator

On your user profile screen you can see a number followed by `/m`

[image]

I'm almost certain that the entire time I've been playing the game it has said `79/m` and `0/m`.
What do these numbers represent?

Comment: I don't know the game, but with absolutely no context at all I would assume that meant either "per minute" or "per meter". Minute seems like it makes more sense from what little context I do have. The m after 5.33 seems like it would be "million".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Those stats are actually what you get when streaming offline when a video is not being made. The first number is the number of views per minute you'd get from streaming, rounded, while the second is the number of new subs you'd get per minute by streaming, which would only increase when you get the Stream Subs Knowledge.

So, in your case, when you don't have the game on, it will generate 79 views a minute, give or take, for however long you'd stream for - normally 60 minutes (one hour) but can be increased to 6 hours.

Answer (score 2):

It stands for per minute - you are getting 79 views per minute, but no subs per minute.

Comment: How exactly would you get subscribers per minute?

Comment: I'm definitely getting way more than 79 views per minute, do you know how it's counting them if thats the case?

Comment: I haven't played the game for very long, so I don't know all the ins and outs of how it decides things. I will poke at it later tonight and see if I can get some clarification

Comment: I did some poking myself, and from what I gathered, it's based on what you get from Streaming.

Comment: Also, the term used is Subs, which is short for Subscribers